# Is there a work around to cast an object from a DataKeyArray to a String in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to cast an object from a DataKeyArray to a String and I get the following error:

`Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataKey' to 'string'`

Is there someone to work around this problem. Here is my code that is producing the error:

```
int index = (int)GridView1.SelectedIndex;
HttpContext.Current.Session["Order"] = (String)GridView1.DataKeys[index];
Response.Redirect("Test.aspx");
```

Comment: Don't you want GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value?

Comment: Thanks psr, that fixed everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`GridView1.DataKeys[Index].Value`